# How to get cities from an array of full address?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm working on an application on which I want my users to select which results to see based on the cities.

Currently the way the application work is a search engine for jobs on which users can specify the following:

- Job Title
- Country

Assuming that the user has added the following preferences `database` in `Cyprus` the following addresses will show up:

Array of 4 elements (cityName, postCode, CountryCode, Street Address)

```
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LARNAKA - SOTIR | 6057 | cy | ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA
STROVOLOS       | 2064 | cy | ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
LAKATAMEIA      | 2322 | cy | Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1 2322 LEFKOSIA
```

I searched online and found out that Cyprus has the following cities: `Lefkosia or Nicosia` `Paphos` `Limassol or Lemesos` `Larnaka or Larnaca` and finally `Ammohostos or Famagusta`.

What I want to figure out is to display only the jobs selected by city name. For example, when a user decides to see only jobs in `Lefkosia or Nicosia` only four result should be shown. That is:

```
STROVOLOS       | 2064 | cy | ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
LAKATAMEIA      | 2322 | cy | Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1 2322 LEFKOSIA
```

I'm not sure what is the best way of doing it. I'm not responsible for how the locations are stored as I'm using web-scraping to get this information. Also in the example above, none of the 4 results provided has a correct way of storing the city-names.

One solution I can think of is to get the last bit of the street-address. But I'm unsure about this. I also have to deal with most of the European countries and not just Cyprus from this example.

If you know how to solve this please let me know.

---

**UPDATE:**

Actual array:

```
0: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
1: "LARNAKA - SOTIR 6057 cy ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA"
2: "EDEGEM 2650 be Acht Eeuwenlaan"
3: "STROVOLOS 2064 cy ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA"
4: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
5: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
6: "EGKOMI 2404 cy Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος  2404 LEFKOSIA"
7: "EGKOMI 2404 cy Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος  2404 LEFKOSIA"
8: "LAKATAMEIA 2322 cy Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1  2322 LEFKOSIA"
```

Comment: I have a question, is the filter done after you collected the data?

Comment: yes I collect data, then i want to filter them and finally display them on client-side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter

```js
const addr = `0: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
1: "LARNAKA - SOTIR 6057 cy ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA"
2: "EDEGEM 2650 be Acht Eeuwenlaan"
3: "STROVOLOS 2064 cy ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA"
4: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
5: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
6: "EGKOMI 2404 cy Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος  2404 LEFKOSIA"
7: "EGKOMI 2404 cy Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος  2404 LEFKOSIA"
8: "LAKATAMEIA 2322 cy Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1  2322 LEFKOSIA"`.split(/\n/);
document.getElementById("cc").addEventListener("input",function() {
  const val = this.value.toLowerCase();
  const lines = addr.filter(line => line.toLowerCase().includes(val))
  document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = lines.join("<br/>");
})
```

```html
<input type="text" id="cc" placeholder="Type city or country" />
<div id="res"></div>
```

---

Older posts:

Use the post code to split:

```js
const addr = `LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LARNAKA - SOTIR | 6057 | cy | ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA
STROVOLOS       | 2064 | cy | ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
LAKATAMEIA      | 2322 | cy | Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1 2322 LEFKOSIA
Den Haag        | 2221AA | nl | Onder de brug 25, 2221AA 's Gravenhage
East End          | E20 6PQ | uk | Albert Square E20 6PQ London`.split(/\n/);
const cities = [...new Set(addr.map(line => {
  const [place,postcode,_,addr] = line.split("|");
  return addr.split(postcode)[1]
  })
)]; 
console.log(cities)
```

In your example and that alone you can use this regex too

```js
const addr = `LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LARNAKA - SOTIR | 6057 | cy | ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA
STROVOLOS       | 2064 | cy | ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
LAKATAMEIA      | 2322 | cy | Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1 2322 LEFKOSIA`.split(/\n/);
const cities = [...new Set(addr.map(line => line.match(/(?:\d)+ (\w+)$/)[1]))]; 
console.log(cities)
```

Update does use the regex again for the actual array you provided

It cannot handle 2: "EDEGEM 2650 be Acht Eeuwenlaan"

```js
const addr = `0: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
1: "LARNAKA - SOTIR 6057 cy ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA"
2: "EDEGEM 2650 be Acht Eeuwenlaan"
3: "STROVOLOS 2064 cy ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA"
4: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
5: "LEMESOS 3042 cy ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS"
6: "EGKOMI 2404 cy Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος  2404 LEFKOSIA"
7: "EGKOMI 2404 cy Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος  2404 LEFKOSIA"
8: "LAKATAMEIA 2322 cy Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1  2322 LEFKOSIA"`.split(/\n/);
const cities = [...new Set(addr.map(line => {
  const pCode = line.match(/(\d{2,}) /)[1];
  return line.split(pCode)[2];
  })
)]; 
console.log(cities)
```

Comment: okay i will try using this and let you know if it works for me. Why this would not work with other list of location?

Comment: The first will not work with Dutch addresses where the post code ie nnnnAA - I added a possibly better version

Comment: See update. Assuming second field is a post code, you should be able to use my code

Comment: I have updated the question with the actual array, I never thought it would be much important in the first place, so i have modified it so it could be clear what im trying to explain. However using the code mentioned in your code, it doesn't work with the actual array giving the following error: `jobs_map.js:75 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null
    at jobs_map.js:75
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at addDataOnMapAndTable (jobs_map.js:75)
    at returnResults:246`

Comment: I updated but cannot handle the mix. - the Dutch address in example 3 does not even have a city

Comment: @user14054150 See last update that filters on anything the user types

Answer (score 0):

```js
const addr = `LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LARNAKA - SOTIR | 6057 | cy | ΣΠΥΡΟΥ ΚΥΠΡΙΑΝΟΥ 50, ΙΡΙΔΑ 3 10-ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 6057 LARNAKA
STROVOLOS       | 2064 | cy | ΒΥΖΑΝΤΙΟΥ 30 FLAT/ OFFICE 22 2064 LEFKOSIA
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
LEMESOS         | 3042 | cy | ΡΙΧΑΡΔΟΥ & ΒΕΡΕΓΓΑΡΙΑΣ 12 ARAOUZOS CASTLE COURT, 3ΟΣ ΟΡΟΦΟΣ 3042 LEMESOS
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
EGKOMI          | 2404 | cy | Διογένους 1, Κόμβος A, 5ος όροφος 2404 LEFKOSIA
LAKATAMEIA      | 2322 | cy | Arch. Makariou III and Mesaorias 1 2322 LEFKOSIA`.split(/\n/);
$.each(addr, function(i, val){
  if(/LEFKOSIA/.test(val)){
    console.log(val);
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I used a jquery each in combination with a regexp.
If you would use user input for the city it will become the following:

```
let regex = RegExp('userInput')
if(regex.test(val)){//true code//}
```

Comment: I assume I have to code all the cities of the entire europe in order to get what I want. I'm not sure if this is a logical way of solving my problem

Comment: @user14054150 you told me that you already collected the data. The little piece of code beneath the snippet is what you could use when there is user input for a city, like if the user were to type in Lefkosia or Larnaka. All I have shown with the snippet is one way to filter the data.

Comment: I think DutchDev meant for you to TYPE the country or city name and then he would extract it. It will work, but will also return "Paris, Texas" if you type "Paris"

Comment: I do not understand why you would load jQuery for a plain filter

Comment: @mplungjan Firstly, yes that is possible. I'm doing that blackbox since I don't know what data would look like for the USA. I just basing my answer on the given situation. For the second, its personal preference since it gives just a bit more options on solving problems with data and client side events.

Comment: I disagree. jQuery is great for DOM access. For string manipulation much less so

`console.log(addr.filter(line => /LEFKOSIA/.test(val))) ` is much nicer